# Jquery form validation Name...It must contain all characters... Help me out

Tags: php, jquery, html

name is Name id
submit is Submit id

help me to convert the code to check it contains all characters(no number and no special characters)

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {                             
       $('.form_error').hide();
       $('#submit').click(function(){
        var name = $('#name').val();
        if(name== '') {
           $('#name').next().show();
           return false;
       } else {
           return true;
       }    

//ajax call php page
 $.post("send.php", 
       $("#contactform").serialize(),  function(response) {
            $('#contactform').fadeOut('slow',function(){
              });
          });
          return false;
      });
 });

</script>       
    <form action="" method="post" id="contactform">
 Name: <input name="name" id="name" type="text" 
 placeholder="Please enter your name" class="contact-input">
  <span class="form_error"> Please enter your valid name</span>
  <br><br>                                      
<input type="submit" class="contactform-buttons" id="submit"value="Send" />

</form>                             
</html>
```

name is Name id
submit is Submit id

Help me to convert the code to check it contains all characters(no number and no special characters)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {       
     $('#name').keypress(function (e) {
                    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z]+$");
                    var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
                    if (regex.test(str)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      e.preventDefault();
                      alert('Please enter only alphabet');
                      return false;
                    }
                });
});
```

***Alternative Method:***

```
    $(function() {
            $('#name').keydown(function(e) {
              if (e.shiftKey || e.ctrlKey || e.altKey) {
                e.preventDefault();
              } else {
                var key = e.keyCode;
                if (!((key == 8) || (key == 32) || (key == 46) || (key >= 35 && key <= 40) || (key >= 65 && key <= 90))) {
                  e.preventDefault();
                }
              }
            });
          });
```

Comment: It's not working yet :(

Where to put the above code which you suggested?

Thanks. :)

Comment: The code should work. The first snippet code warns you to enter only alphabets if non- alphabets is typed in the textbox and the second snippet code doesn't allow you to type non-alphabet in the textbox. You can use either of one(among two codes) as per your requirement in your case. You can put the code under <script type="text/javascript">  anywhere you like.